# object Object displaying in browser with Ext.DomHelper.insertHtml

Tags: extjs, extjs3

I appreciate the patience in advance, as I am new to ExtJS. I am trying to add an html element when loading my store. Currently, it is appending the object [object Object] to the page, but I need to display the div itself. The tileDiv in the DomHelper line is my issue. My code is as follows:

```
function handleKeyUp(e) {
   var code = e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which;
   if (code === 38) { //up key
      alert('up');
   } else if (code === 40) { //down key
      alert('down');
   }
}
var tileDiv = new Ext.Element({
   tag: 'div',
   id: tileId,
   cls: 'tile',
   html: html,
   listeners: {
      keyup: handleKeyUp,
      scope: this
   }
});
Ext.DomHelper.insertHtml('beforeEnd', this.el.dom, tileDiv);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are confusing Ext elements with HTML DOM elements. An Ext Element is an object created by ExtJS that wraps a DOM element.

Look at the doc:

```
insertHtml( where, el, html ) : HTMLElement
Inserts an HTML fragment into the DOM.
```

It expects the last statement to be an HTML fragment. You are passing an Ext.Element.

What you are probably trying to do is something like this:

```
Ext.onReady(function(){
    Ext.DomHelper.append(Ext.getBody(), {
        tag: 'div',
        id: 'tileId',
        cls: 'tile',
        html: '<h1>Hello world</h1>',
        listeners: {
           keyup: function handleKeyUp(e) {
                var code = e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which;
                if (code === 38) { //up key
                    alert('up');
                } else if (code === 40) { //down key
                    alert('down');
                }
            },
           scope: this
        }
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/RCXdL/

Please note that your event handler onKeyUp will only work on focusable elements. (see http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/keys.html)

Comment: You were absolutely right about my confusion. I used append and it worked. I can't thank you enough!